# AWS IAM Policy to allow user to create IAM User with specific Policy/Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to create a policy that allows for the creation of IAM users that have limited permissions or the same permissions as the user that created them.

Basically; I want to allow a user to create another user, but to also specify exactly what policies one user is allowed to give to another user.

For example;

I create a new user: User A

User A only has permissions to create new users with (equally) limited permissions.

User A create a new user: User B

User B only has the same permissions as User A (or fewer/different permissions).

I thought maybe it was something in the resource section? Eg

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToPerformUserActions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateUser",
      ],
      "Resource": "<Some Specific Policy>"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can't. As long as your user **A** can create a user and [attach a managed policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_AttachUserPolicy.html) or [add an inline policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_PutUserPolicy.html) to the newly-created user, this policy is just a document that could contain any permission.

Comment: I thought that would probably be the case. I'm sure there are a number of valid reasons, mostly around security, as to why it isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating a new user, you can use the [`GetSessionToken`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html) command from the AWS Security Token Service.

This command allows any user to create **temporary credentials** with the same permissions that they have, or with permissions scoped-down from their own permissions. (It will never have more permissions that the requesting user.)

The temporary credentials can be valid for **15 minutes to 1 hour**.

These types of credentials are typically used to activate a multi-factor authentication session or to create temporary credentials for an untrusted application.

Comment: Thanks! I reckon that is probably the next best thing!