# Allow a user to create additional users and policies only for resources he created/own

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

Am I able to allow a newly created IAM user to create arbitrary policies but limited to resources he created? For example if I allow a user to create S3 buckets, users and IAM/Bucket policies, I want him to be able to create policies for IAM user that are limited to buckets he created and not other buckets present in the account.

If I'm not able to specify such policy, is there any other way to achieve this? Some kind of namespacing within an account that could isolate that user's resources from all other IAM users?

This is related to [AWS IAM Policy to allow user to create IAM User with specific Policy/Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412293/aws-iam-policy-to-allow-user-to-create-iam-user-with-specific-policy-roles) and I was wondering if something has changed since the time it was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Delegate permission management to developers by using IAM permissions boundaries](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/delegate-permission-management-to-developers-using-iam-permissions-boundaries/)

The documentation [Permissions boundaries for IAM entities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html)

> AWS supports permissions boundaries for IAM entities (users or roles). A permissions boundary is an advanced feature for using a managed policy to set the maximum permissions that an identity-based policy can grant to an IAM entity. An entity's permissions boundary allows it to perform only the actions that are allowed by both its identity-based policies and its permissions boundaries